# javascript removes only every second element

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I've discovered a Problem ...
I'm writing a userscript for grease- and tampemonkey which should change a websites look.

One of my tasks is to remove every image with the title `New Post`
(`<img src="..." title="New Post" alt="...">`)

i have the following snipplet:

```
elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

alert(elements.length); // FIRST

for (i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    image = elements[i];

    if (image.title.search(/New\ Post/) > -1) {
        image.remove();
    }
}

alert(i); // SECOND
```

This snipplet removes images, but only every second.
The first alert gives me the number `19` but the second alert gives `10` ...

The script should delete every image tag with the given title.
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Tip: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.log

Comment: @richieahb - I think this wont work within a userscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` returns a live list, that means when you call remove() on an element in the returned list the removed item will get removed from the array also.

[document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)

> Returns an HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name. The
>   complete document is searched, including the root node. **The returned
>   HTMLCollection is live, meaning that it updates itself automatically
>   to stay in sync with the DOM tree without having to call
>   document.getElementsByTagName() again**.

try

```js
var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).appendTo($log)
  }
})();


var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

log('initial: ' + elements.length);

for (i = 0; i < elements.length;) {
  image = elements[i];

  if (image.title.search(/New\ Post/) > -1) {
    image.remove();
    log('remove: ' + elements.length);
  } else {
    i++
    log('not: ' + elements.length);
  }
}

log('end: ' + elements.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img title="New Post" src="//placehold.it/64/fff000" />
<img title="New1 Post" src="//placehold.it/64/000fff" />
<img title="New Post" src="//placehold.it/64/fff000" />
<img title="New1 Post" src="//placehold.it/64/000fff" />
<img title="New Post" src="//placehold.it/64/fff000" />
<img title="New1 Post" src="//placehold.it/64/000fff" />

<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're removing elements whilst looping through the list you're removing them from.  At the point where you've removed more than are left, `i` is the same as `elements.length` so the loop exits before they're all removed.

Try removing them in reverse order:

```
for (i=elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    image = elements[i];

    if (image.title.search(/New\ Post/) > -1) {
        image.remove();
    }
}
```

This way removing elements from the end of the list shouldn't affect your position in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Only increment the loop counter if you're not removing an image:

```
for (i=0; i < elements.length; ) {
    image = elements[i];

    if (image.title.search(/New\ Post/) > -1) image.remove();
    else i++;
}
```